# Send Email When Calander Entry Is Made

Tags: workflow

I am new to SharePoint and creating Workflow through SharePoint Designer 2013. We have a conference room that users need to book through Calendar App. I have created the calendar app and now need a workflow that can automatically send email notification to the attendees selected/entered as soon as an entry (booking) is made. I am using the default columns. I know it is basic but any assistance is very much appreciated.

Thank you

Teine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the steps mentioned below
1. Click on Workflow on the left navigation under sharepoint designer.
[image]

2. Now, Click on the "List Workflow" button in the ribbon bar and then select the Calendar app/list.

[image]

3. Enter the name of the workflow
   [image]
4. Now you can start creating the workflow, In the stage 1, Click and then start writing email. then you will see the "press enter to insert send email" option (ref pic below). 
   Press enter.
   [image]
5. Now follow the steps mentioned in the below picture in sequence.
   [image]
6. Add the subject and the message as shown in the picture below and click on OK
   [image]
7. Ensure to end the workflow, 
   Click in the "Transition to stage" section and write "Go" then you can select "End of Workflow"
   [image]
8. Now, Save and publish this workflow.
9. Now, click on Workflow in the left navigation so as to list the workflow. Here you can go to settings (refer below pic).
   [image]
10. On the settings page select one of the Start options.
11. Ensure to save and publish the workflow again.

Now you should be able to go ahead and create booking in the calendar under SharePoint and send the notification to Attendees

Comment: Thank you very much. Just created that and it worked. I did not add áttendees'to Event. Added that and created the workflow and volla, worked perfectly.